# Not understanding the code written in jenkins file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

i have found the following code in a jenkins file in my project. i am new to aws and docker and not understanding the logic behind this code, guys help me out on what is happening here

```
            sh "docker run --rm -i -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -e AWS_REGION " +
               '--name "${CONTAINER_ID}" "${IMAGE_TAG}" ' +
               "node -r esbuild-runner/register ./scripts/restartExecution.ts " +

               (params.DryRun? "--dry-run " : "") +
               "--started-after ${StartedAfter} " +
               (params.StartedBefore? "--started-before ${params.StartedBefore} " : "") +
               "--state-machine-arn ${params.StateMachineARN} " +
               "--status ${params.Status} "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward

```
docker run --rm -i -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -e AWS_REGION '--name "${CONTAINER_ID}" "${IMAGE_TAG}" '
```

The docker run command first creates a container layer over the specified image, and then starts it using the specified command.(from docs)
Pass the three

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_REGION
```

as environmental variables.

Sometimes it is useful to show the commands that a shell script will execute,that is why `dry-run` was added.

More about options in [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

-rm remove container after it exits
-i interactive mode

Comment: Thanks @Richard, what does --rm -i -e options means